# Why am I still able to write to a directory after I have changed permissions at the terminal?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sudo, chmod

I am running Mac Os 10.9 and connecting to a Mac OS server (10.8?) over our local network where I have an admin account.

I regularly sync 3 directories from my machine to the fileserver using `rsync`. I would like to make these read-only so people don't go adding their own things to my folder.

When I `ssh` into the other machine, I can make changes with `chmod` and those changes are verifiable with `ls`. However, if I connect to the same directory using `afp` as a different user and from another machine, I am still able to make changes through the GUI (delete, edit, etc.).

How can I make changes to file permissions of a remote directory via `ssh` such that they will be propagated to the GUI?

When I try to run `sudo chmod` in the remote session it tells me that I am not in the sudoers file. However, as I am the owner of the file I can still change its permissions without `sudo`.

Comment: Many network filesystems have a short-duration cache for things like permissions.  How long does this affect last?

Comment: I don't know. I'll have a look tomorrow morning to see if things have changed at all. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

[AFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol) could be using `SMB`, `NFS`, `FTP` or `WebDAV`... all of which provide independent file access controls and overrides (depending on configuration).  If these other users all connect through `AFP` it might be better to change the configuration on the folder so it's read only (regardless of filesystem permissions).

Such a change would only effect `AFP` connections, not your `SSH` or `rsync` connections (I'm assuming you're using rsync over ssh)

Comment: In fact, I mount the remote drive via AFP and send the files using the following:

`rsync -avz --chmod=u=rwX,go=rX -p --delete /Users/myaccount/src/ /Volumes/remoteserver/dest/`